# set global variable parameter?

Tags: mysql, performance, myisam, mysql-5.1, query-performance

My prod_server version is 5.1.47 and want to set the slow query log dynamically for certain period of time.
I refered one site(http://toastergremlin.com/?p=276) there is mentioned below 5.1.6 we need to set the variables into the my.cnf, but my prod_server is critical can't take my server restart is there any way we set variables dynamically for certain period of time?

Thank u in advance please help.

Comment: use  set global slow_query_log=1 to turn on slow query log on the fly. by default slow wait time is 10 sec.  Use set global variable=value to set any global variable to some value of your choice. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set any global variables to any value on the fly using below statement in MySQL prompt:

```
set global <variable> = <value>;
```

In your case use the following to turn on slow query log:

```
 set global slow_query_log=1;
```

By default the "slow wait time" is set to 10 sec, but you can change it as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: (1) Yes, do lower the long_query_time.  10 is almost useless.  I like 2.  (2) Also, keep in mind that existing connections will not see the GLOBAL values; only new connections.  (3) Use pt-query-digest for summarizing the slowlog.  (4) I recommend leaving it on all the time, even in production.